# How can i added more than one bank account for a customer with stripe ach payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

Recently, I am working on a investment collection related website in USA. I am using STRIPE API for ACH payment for collecting investment from our clients.

At present, I am using plaid api and stripe for opening stripe customer id and creating charge. but for manual bank account add, I am using stripe.js.

My question is our invidual customer can add more than one bank to their account. how can i do it with stripe for ach payments.

In a line, my question is how can i add more than one bank account for stripe customer id. and how can i charge for every individual bank account with stripe API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's covered in the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_create_bank_account

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create/add a bank account of a `CUSTOMER_ID` by this [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_create_bank_account).
2. You can update/change individual bank account in Stripe by this [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_update_bank_account)

Comment: but what if i want to add more than 1 bank account?

Comment: Can you make me clear? Are you trying to add more than account by single API request? Or trying to add more account to a customer (previously created with bank account) who already have bank account then you trying to add new bank account?

Comment: yes, i have created customer with bank account. but i want to add another source.

Comment: Then get customer by ID using API then add desired source. Even API documentation having this example!